# Shift specific strings pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am trying to shift specific `strings` in a `pandas` `df` up a `row`. These `strings` are located in the same or adjacent columns.

The df below is an example. The designated strings are `Cat`, `Dog`. I want to shift these values up a `row`. These values are in both `Column C` and `Column D`.

```
import pandas as pd 

d = ({
    'A' : ['A','Yy','A','Xy','A','Zy','Yy'],
    'B' : ['Big','X','Big','X','Very','X','X'],           
    'C' : ['','Cat','YY','Dog','Big','XY','YY'],
    'D' : ['','','Xy','Yy','','Cat','Yy'],
    'E' : ['','','Xy','XX','','','Xy'],           
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My intended output is

```
    A     B    C    D   E
0   A   Big  Cat         
1  Yy     X              
2   A   Big  Dog   Xy  Xy
3  Xy     X        Yy  XX
4   A  Very  Big  Cat    
5  Zy     X   XY         
6  Yy     X   YY   Yy  Xy
```

I have tried:

`df['C'] = df['C'].shift(-1)`

But this shifts up all values. I just want to select specific values (e.g. `Cat`, `Dog`) in certain columns and shift them up a row.

I was thinking about making a list of designated values and then shifting those up. Something like

`val  = ['Cat','Dog']`

`if val is in df['C',D'].shift up one row`

**Note:** I can't sort this based off the surrounding strings. My actual df contains various different strings that would take too long to go through.

Comment: Do you know beforehand which vars to shift? Do you know their position ?

Comment: I don't understand the logic

Comment: Can do `df.iat[x-1,y] = df.iat[x,y]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [df.combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html),

```
mylist=['Cat','Dog']
a=df[df.isin(mylist)].shift(-1)
df[df.isin(mylist)]=""
out_df=a.combine_first(df)
print(out_df)
    A     B    C    D   E
0   A   Big  Cat         
1  Yy     X              
2   A   Big  Dog   Xy  Xy
3  Xy     X        Yy  XX
4   A  Very  Big  Cat    
5  Zy     X   XY         
6  Yy     X   YY   Yy  XyX
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case do:

```
df['C'][0],df['C'][1] = df['C'][1],df['C'][0] # swap the index
df['D'] = df['D'].shift(-1).fillna('X')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B       C      D  E
0    A  Big     Cat          
1    X    X                  
2    X    X       X      X  X
3    X    X       X      X  X
4  Foo  Bar  Foobar  Fubur   
5    X    X       X          
6    X    X       X      X  X
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generalized solution, use Pandas `eq()` with `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

def shift_value(df, value):
    row, col = np.where(df.eq(value))
    old_row = row[0]
    old_col = col[0]
    new_row = old_row - 1
    new_col = old_col
    df.iat[new_row, new_col] = value
    df.iat[old_row, old_col] = "X"

for v in ["Cat", "Foobar"]:
    shift_value(df, v)

df
     A    B       C      D  E
0    A  Big     Cat          
1    X    X       X          
2    X    X       X      X  X
3    X    X  Foobar      X  X
4  Foo  Bar       X          
5    X    X       X  Fubur   
6    X    X       X      X  X
```

Original OP data:

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['A','X','X','X','Foo','X','X'],
    'B' : ['Big','X','X','X','Bar','X','X'],           
    'C' : ['','Cat','X','X','Foobar','X','X'],
    'D' : ['','','X','X','','Fubur','X'],
    'E' : ['','','X','X','','','X'],           
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Sorry, The X only signified other strings. They actual string values are huge. I cant sort through each one

Comment: Sorry for altering the original data. But your export still wouldn't work. `Foobar` and `Fubur` are in the wrong rows

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is that all the value in the row which has a single meaningful word to be shifted, this should be an answer:

```
In [36]: import pandas as pd
    ...: d = ({
    ...:     'A' : ['A','X','X','X','Foo','X','X'],
    ...:     'B' : ['Big','X','X','X','Bar','X','X'],
    ...:     'C' : ['','Cat','X','X','Foobar','X','X'],
    ...:     'D' : ['','','X','X','','Fubur','X'],
    ...:     'E' : ['','','X','X','','','X'],
    ...:     })
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    ...:
    ...: index = ((df!='X') & (df!='') & df.notna()).sum(axis=1) == 1
    ...: for row in df[index].index.values:
    ...:     for col in df.columns.values:
    ...:         if df.loc[row, col]!='X' and bool(df.loc[row, col]):
    ...:             df.loc[row-1, col] = df.loc[row, col]
    ...:             df.loc[row, col] = ''
    ...:

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
     A    B       C      D  E
0    A  Big     Cat
1    X    X
2    X    X       X      X  X
3    X    X       X      X  X
4  Foo  Bar  Foobar  Fubur
5    X    X       X
6    X    X       X      X  X
```

Comment: Sorry @Woods Chen. I can't do this based off X as a string. My actual dataset contains far too many various strings to sort off

Answer (score 0):

So, you can try a for loop if the data is not too big:

```
for row in range(1, len(df)):
    for col in df.columns.values:
        if (df.loc[row, col] != '') and (df.loc[row-1, col] == ''):
            df.loc[row-1, col] = df.loc[row, col]
            df.loc[row, col] = '######'
df = df.replace('######', '')
```